# @NotifyChange doesn't work

Tags: java, zk

So in my ZUL I have :

```
<label value="Montant HT" />
<textbox id="totalSoldDF" readonly="true" style="text-align: center"
                    value="@load(c:formatNumber(vm.totalSoldDF, '#,###.##€'))" />
```

and I'm trying to update this field like this :

```
@NotifyChange({"totalSoldDF"})
public void countTotalSold() {

    totalSoldDF = 0;
    for (Profile p : profileList) {
        totalSoldDF += pen.getTotal();
    }
}
```

But nothing happens and I'm sure that the variable is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@NotifyChange` do work, but you need to use it correct.
The annotation can only be set on `setters` and on `commands` as described [in the documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Syntax/ViewModel/@NotifyChange).

Now, don't worry, there is [another method](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/ViewModel/Notification#Notify_Programmatically) what you can do :

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null,null,this,"totalSoldDF");
```